# Nodelets - Can the publisher and subscriber be in two different packages?

Tags: ros, nodelet, nodelet-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying my first implementation of nodelets for faster camera image acquisition and publishing. I have followed the nodelet implementation for the camera1394 ROS driver, and I have made this into a separate package. My doubt was regarding the subscriber. From what I understand, I can have the subscriber as its own package just inheriting from nodelet class and overloading the onInit method. Then for running the nodelets, I simply launch one nodelet_manager and launch the nodelet-publisher and nodelet-subscriber in that. The subscriber package does not need to depend on the publisher package. Is this correct?

The launch sequence on command-line would be:

1. rosrun nodelet nodelet manager __name:=nodelet_manager
2. rosrun nodelet nodelet load publisher_nodelet/image_publisher nodelet_manager __name:=image_publisher
3. rosrun nodelet nodelet load subscriber_nodelet/image_subscriber nodelet_manager __name:=image_subscriber

All the tutorials on nodelets that I have seen show the subscriber and the publisher in the same package - which is what has caused this doubt. I was wondering if that was a requirement or just a simplification for the tutorials.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/106461/nodelets---can-the-publisher-and-subscriber-be-in-two-different-packages?/) by [NikhilD](https://answers.ros.org/users/9216/nikhild/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-12-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes the nodelets loaded into the manager can come from any package on the system.

(Assuming it's been compiled etc.)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0